# how i can select some attribute value from in line css

Tags: jquery, css

```
<ul><li><div id="top" style="margin-left:58px;">it is a div</div ></li></ul>
```

How i can fetch value of `margin-left(85px)` from the given inline css using jquery.       here i able to access value of style attribute as  (margin-left:58px;). but i need only 85 as an integer value so i can use it to apply some arithmatic operation on it . then i want to apply same css on it with different  margin-left value as (85 multiply by 2.5).   so how i can fetch value and how i can apply css on it .

Comment: yes sir i have tried and got the result a string  as margin-left:58px , but i need only 58(integer or float) ,not margin-left: and px Concatenated  with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get left margin of the div this way:

```
 $("#top").css("margin-left");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('#top').css('margin-left', function(index, value){
    return parseInt(value, 10) * 2.5;
});
```

This means: get the `margin-left` style, parse it to the integer value (with radix=10), multiply it by 2.5, and then return the value to the element.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //grab the value of style for id top
  var value = $('#top).attr('style');
  alert(value);
});
```

Comment: He said 'how can I fetch the value', not 'how i can fetch the CSS rule'